# Setting BIRT datasource through its API

Tags: java, jdbc, birt

I'm looking for some direction for coding the BIRT API w/ a datasource.  I'm unsure of how to configure my application to access a created datasource.  If I can get some help w/this it would be great.  Here's where I am.  I've already created a report through BIRT RCP.  Now I'm looking to generate the report using a regular java application AND a web application.  Both will be passing in date parameters through a GUI that I'll be creating.  Both need to have a datasource.  I've have seen some examples here that use the Report Designer however I am not using that.  I'm also NOT using the BIRT Report Creator (RCP) GUI to generate this.

Thanks

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.Platform;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineConfig;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.HTMLRenderOption;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IReportEngine;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IReportEngineFactory;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IReportRunnable;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IRunAndRenderTask;

public class ReportGenerator {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws EngineException {
        ReportGenerator reportGenerator = new ReportGenerator();
        reportGenerator.executeReport();
    }

    public void executeReport() throws EngineException {

        IReportEngine engine=null;
        EngineConfig config = null;

        try{
            config = new EngineConfig( );           
            config.setBIRTHome("C:\\birt-rcp-report-designer-3_7_2\\ReportEngine");
            config.setLogConfig("c:/temp/test", Level.FINEST);
            Platform.startup( config );
            IReportEngineFactory factory = (IReportEngineFactory) Platform.createFactoryObject( IReportEngineFactory.EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY );
            engine = factory.createReportEngine( config );      

            IReportRunnable design = null;
            //Open the report design
            design = engine.openReportDesign("ReportTemplates/testNoData.rptdesign"); 
            IRunAndRenderTask task = engine.createRunAndRenderTask(design);
            task.setParameterValue("AuthorName", "Dale DeMott");
            HTMLRenderOption options = new HTMLRenderOption();      
            options.setOutputFileName("output/resample/Parmdisp.html");
            options.setOutputFormat("html");

            task.setRenderOption(options);

            //Looking to create and insert a datasource here.
            //task.setDataSource(some parameters here that represent the ds);

            task.run();
            task.close();
            engine.destroy();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            Platform.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Researching this deeper I found the solution to my own question and thought I'd share the answer.

To clarify I was looking for a way to connect my code to a `datasource`, so my `BIRT` report queries would run. I found that, I can pass in a connection via the `IGetParameterDefinitionTask` object by getting the application context then setting the connection in this object through a key value pair setting.

See this line in the code below... 
`task.getAppContext().put("OdaJDBCDriverPassInConnection", conn);`

```
public class ReportGenerator {
public static void main(String args[]) throws EngineException {
    ReportGenerator reportGenerator = new ReportGenerator();
    reportGenerator.executeReport();
}

public void executeReport() throws EngineException {

    IReportEngine engine=null;
    EngineConfig config = null;

    try{
        config = new EngineConfig( );           
        config.setBIRTHome("C:\\birt-rcp-report-designer-3_7_2\\ReportEngine");
        config.setLogConfig("c:/temp/test", Level.FINEST);
        Platform.startup( config );
        IReportEngineFactory factory = (IReportEngineFactory) Platform.createFactoryObject( IReportEngineFactory.EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY );
        engine = factory.createReportEngine( config );      

        IReportRunnable design = null;
        //Open the report design
        design = engine.openReportDesign("ReportTemplates/testNoData.rptdesign"); 
        IRunAndRenderTask task = engine.createRunAndRenderTask(design);
        task.setParameterValue("AuthorName", "Dale DeMott");
        HTMLRenderOption options = new HTMLRenderOption();      
        options.setOutputFileName("output/resample/Parmdisp.html");
        options.setOutputFormat("html");

        task.setRenderOption(options);

        //Connection helper is a utility class used to create a connection to your
        //database and return it.  
        ConnectionHelper connectionHelper = new ConnectionHelper();
        Connection conn = connectionHelper.getConnection();
        task.getAppContext().put("OdaJDBCDriverPassInConnection", conn);

        task.run();
        task.close();
        engine.destroy();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        Platform.shutdown();
    }
}
}
```